# How can i dispatch redux actions?

Tags: typescript, react-redux

I'm trying to build a sample app with authorization. Using redux and typescript.

The action loginUser in actions.tsx runs but the reduced one not.

Below you can find my code
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-auth-with-redux-3p38q

The issue occurs in file index.tsx while dispatching the login action (line 89).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not dispatching an actual action, but only the function that creates the action. So change

```
return dispatch(loginSuccess);
```

to

```
return dispatch(loginSuccess());
```

Running `loginSuccess()` creates the action, then that gets dispatched.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! But the error remains in index.tsx any idea why?

Comment: Looks like it has something to do with the typescript types, I think because the loginUsers is a thunk action this doesn't match. Don't have an instant fix, but maybe this will help you fix it: https://redux.js.org/recipes/usage-with-typescript/#usage-with-redux-thunk or maybe this one https://github.com/piotrwitek/react-redux-typescript-guide